# Divide a string into collection string with length of 3

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Say I have a string `var s = "123456789"`

where

```
foreach(var c in DivideStr(s, 3)){
  Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

would print out `123` , `456`, `789`

This is a fairly easy problem to accomplish with loop and if statement.  But I want to accomplish with `Take` and `Skip` function in C# in the follow fashion

```
IEnumerable DivideStr(String s, Int n) 
{
   var a = s;  
   while(!a.IsEmpty())  
   {  
     yield return a.Take(n)  
     a = a.Drop(3) // or a.Skip(n)  
   }  
}
```

This way, if I have `var s = "12345678"`
The print out would be `123`, `456`, and `78`

The problem is the above code won't compile. What am I missing?

Comment: What question do you have specifically?  I have all sorts of ideas, but I doubt any of them are relevant to your question.

Comment: what would you expect this to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
IEnumerable<string> splitstrings = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 3)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * 3, 3));
```

Or this

```
List<string> splitstrings = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\d{1,3}")
                   select m.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If `s` is `"12345678"`, this will yield `123`, `456`, and then `78`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> DivideStr(String s, int n)
    {
        for (int currentPos = 0; currentPos < s.Length; currentPos += n)
        {
            yield return new string(s.Skip(currentPos).Take(n).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Although using `Skip` and `Take` in this manner doesn't make much practical sense, because we might as well yield `s.Substring(...)`-s without any enumerator overhead.

Comment: using Substring means you need to check ArrayOutOfBound condition